# Suffle dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, multidimensional-array

The columns present in the .ods file are: Fuel Name, Unit of Measure, Refinery, State, Year, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December, Total. The columns for the months contain the corresponding sales figures for that month, and the Total column contains the sum of the values ​​for each month of the corresponding row. However, in some file conversions, the month and total values ​​shuffle n + k places to the right, starting from the first line, with k being incremented by 1 for each following line. More specifically, the first line suffers a shuffle of n squares, the second line suffers a shuffle of n + 1 squares, the third line suffers a shuffle of n + 2 squares ... the thirteenth line suffers a shuffle of 13 squares ( returning to the original configuration), and so on until the end of the file.
Internally, you and your teammates have dubbed this problem "stair".

First line example:

Right:
Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec Total

1000 2500 1200 3000 1234 700 300 1000 0 800 2400 3500 17634

With n = 4 shuffle:

Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr May  Jun  Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec Total

800 2400 3500 17634 1000 2500 1200 3000 1234 700 300 1000 0

With n = 1 shuffle:

Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec Total

17634 1000 2500 1200 3000 1234 700 300 1000 0 800 2400 3500

Transforming the files into matrices, only with the columns above, we will have the following examples: Examples of desired patterns (correct matrix or step ladder):

```
1 matrixCorrect = [
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78],
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78],
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78],
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78],
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78],
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78],
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78],
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78],
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78],
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78],
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78],
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78]
 #]
```

```
2 matrixUsable_1 = [
# [11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
# [10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
# [9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
# [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 2, 1, 78, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
# [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
# [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
# [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3, 4],
# [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3],
# [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2],
# [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1],
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78],
# [78, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
#]
```

```
3 matrixInusable_2 = [
# [11, 12, 1, 2, 78, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
# [10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
# [9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 78],
# [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 2, 1, 78, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
# [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
# [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
# [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3, 4],
# [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3],
# [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2],
# [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1],
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78],
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78]
#]
```

NOTE: The examples above are merely illustrative. Remember that each row and column will have different values, not repeated as in the matrices above. The examples have been described thus for better understanding. There will always be integer values ​​for each month, and at least one column with the total value corresponding to the sum of the months' values.

To solve the problem, deliver code that:

1. Check for a staircase, given a matrix like the examples above.
2. If there is a ladder, map the data correctly, returning the correct matrix.
3. If there is no step, return if the matrix has a format that can be used (correct pattern) or if it corresponds to an unusable pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np


matrizCorreta = np.array([ 
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78], 
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78], 
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78], 
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78], 
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78], 
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78], 
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78], 
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78], 
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78], 
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78], 
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78]
 ])

matrizInutilizavel_1 =  np.array([ 
 [11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
 [10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
 [9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
 [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 2, 1, 78, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
 [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
 [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3], 
 [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2], 
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1], 
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78], 
 [78, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12] 
 ])


matrizInutilizavel_2 =  np.array([ 
 [11, 12, 1, 2, 78, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
 [10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
 [9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 78],
 [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 2, 1, 78, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
 [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
 [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2, 3], 
 [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1, 2], 
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78, 1], 
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78], 
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 78] 
 ])



### função recebe uma array 2d qualquer e retorna uma nova array ordenada
def verificacaoMatriz (matriz):
    nova_matriz = []
    ## numero de linhas da matriz
    rows = matriz.shape[0]
    #Número de colunas da matriz
    cols = matriz.shape[1]
    #para todo X no range de 0 até o numero de itens - 1
    for x in range(0,rows-1):
         #para todo Y no range de 0 até o numero de itens - 1
        for y in range(0,cols-1):
            ## Se o valor atual da matriz (linha,coluna) for igual ao próximo valor da diagonal (linha+1,coluna + 1)
            ## Exemplo, valor (0,0) contra (1,1), faça:
            if(matriz[x,y] == matriz[x+1,y+1]):
                ### Ordena todas as linhas da matriz usando a função sort do numpy
                nova_matriz = np.sort(matriz)
    ### se a variavel nova matriz está vazia, significa que a matriz estava correta e não precisou de ordenação
    ### Então só atribuo a matriz original a esta
    if not len(nova_matriz):
        nova_matriz = matriz
    ### Verifica se a array está em ordem            
    is_sorted = lambda a: np.all(a[:-1] <= a[1:])
    if(is_sorted(nova_matriz)==True):
        print("Matriz Correta")
    else:
        print("Matriz Inutilizável")
    return nova_matriz        



#### Testando a matriz Correta
matriz1 = verificacaoMatriz(matrizCorreta)
print("Matriz1",matriz1)

#### Testando a matriz inutil1 
matriz2 = verificacaoMatriz(matrizInutilizavel_1)
print("Matriz2",matriz2)


#### Testando a matriz inutil2
matriz3 = verificacaoMatriz(matrizInutilizavel_2)
print("Matriz3",matriz3)
```